# ¿Cómo borrar y volver a escribir con efecto de cursor Type Writer jQuery?

Tags: jquery

En la siguiente plantilla de [demostración](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/05-05-2017/best_pets-demo_Free/1154779719/web/index.html) el texto se escribe y, luego se borra y, se vuelve a escribir con su respectivo efecto de cursor de escritura.

Logrando obtener el siguiente efecto usando solo `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var msg = 'Mensaje de prueba...';
 var k = 0;
 var char = 0;
 var output = $('#page-two');

 var app = {
  init: function(text, target){
   target.html('');
   char = text.length;
   this.sayHello(text, target);
  },
  sayHello: function(text, target){
   target.append(text[k]);
   console.log(k);
   if(k < char){
    var that = this;
    k++;
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
     that.sayHello(text, target);
    }, 80);
   }
  }
 };
 app.init(msg, output);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 boz-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif
}
body{
 background: linear-gradient(135deg,#00C4FF,#9D1BB2);
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <section id="container">
  <div id="page-two"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </section>
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que tenga el efecto de borrar y, volver a escribir con el respectivo cursor de escritura al igual que la plantilla de [demostración](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/05-05-2017/best_pets-demo_Free/1154779719/web/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el css del cursos lo saque de la misma web de tu ejemplo:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){

        var msg = 'Mensaje de prueba...';
        var k = 0;
        var char = 0;
        var output = $('#page-two');
        var back=false; // valida si se suma o se resta

        var app = {
            init: function(text, target){
                target.html('');
                char = text.length;
                this.sayHello(text, target);
            },
            sayHello: function(text, target){
                target.text(text.slice(0,k));
                var that = this;
 
                if(!back){ //valida que sea false

                    if(k ==text.length)back=!back ; // valida si k es igual longitud del arreglo para ir hacia atras
                    k++;
                }else{
                    k--; 
                    if(k == 0) back=!back; // valida que k sea igual a 0 para ir hacia adelante
                }

                var timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    that.sayHello(text, target);
                }, 80);
            }
        };
        app.init(msg, output);
    });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');

    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        boz-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif
    }
    body{
        background: linear-gradient(135deg,#00C4FF,#9D1BB2);
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
 /* cursos effect */ 
 .typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

@-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="container">
  <span id="page-two"></span><span class="typed-cursor">|</span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo planteado a la solución :)

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo con borrar y volver a escribir:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var msg = 'Mensaje de prueba...';
 var k = 0;
  var l = 0;
 var char = 0;
 var output = $('#page-two');

 var app = {
  init: function(text, target){
   target.html('');
   char = text.length;
   this.sayHello(text, target);
  },
  sayHello: function(text, target){   
   var that = this;
   if(k < char){    
                            target.append(text[k]);
       k++;
                            l = k;
       var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    that.sayHello(text, target);
       }, 80);
   } else {        
                            l--;
                            var newText = msg.substring(0, l);
                            target.html(newText);
                            var timer = setTimeout(function(){
     that.sayHello(text, target);
       }, 80);
                            if (l == 0) {
                                k = 0;
                            }
                       }
  }
 };
 app.init(msg, output);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 boz-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif
}
body{
 background: linear-gradient(135deg,#00C4FF,#9D1BB2);
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <section id="container">
  <div id="page-two"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo dedicado saludos :)